# Call Method when exception is raised, there are multiple exception listed after try block

Tags: python, python-3.x, try-except

Hi i have code where after try block there are multiple exception blocks, i wan to call a specific method when any of the exception is occurred. i don't want to call my method in every exception.

here is my code sample

```
    try:
       print(q)
       a = 8 / 0
    except ZeroDivisionError as z_err:
        new_method(z_err)
        # it's logger operation
    except UnboundLocalError as ub_err:
       new_method(ub_err)
       # it's logger operation
    except NameError as err:
       new_method(err)
       # no log operation.
    except customException1 as err:
       new_method(err)
       # log 2 method
```

basically my method required the exception as argument. also in some exception some specific type of log operation i have to performed. not all exception have logger operation.

i don't want to call this method in every exception because i have more than 10 exception listed.

if any one have any solutions please share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after lot of discussion and review the ans given to my question i have come up with the bellow solution.

```
err_mesg = None
try:
   print(q)
   a = 8 / 0
except (ZeroDivisionError, UnboundLocalError) as z_err:
    err_msg = z_err
    # it's logger operation
except (NameError, customException1, customException2) as err:
   err_msg = err
   # no log operation.
except (customException3, customException4) as err:
   err_msg = err
   # logger second operation

if err_msg:
   new_method(err_msg)
```

this the best possible outcome for my problem. as per my research
thanks @Abhijith Asokan and @Soma Siddhartha

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
try:
   print(q)
   a = 8 / 0
except (ZeroDivisionError ,UnboundLocalError, NameError) as err:
   new_method(err)
```

Comment: thanks for your Ans, it's correct, but i want little more specified solution. because there are some exception in which i have to performed some logger operations. not in all exception logger operation is performed.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to treat all the exceptions the same way, you could just use one except block, that is:

```
try:
   <your code here>
except Exception as e:
   new_method(e)
```

However, it is better to handle exceptions individually or according to your needs, you could also use a `tuple of exceptions` in your except block. For example,

```
try:
   <your code here>
except (ValueError, TypeError, ZeroDivisionError) as e:
   new_method(e)
```

I see, so you could create a tuple for all those exceptions for which you need to log and another tuple for those exceptions for which you don't need to.

Comment: thanks, but  i have to performed some  extra logger operation in specific exception, not in all exception.

Comment: @SagarT I added a comment in my answer. I guess that's the best you could do. I am not sure what else can be done

Answer (score 0):

**You can classify the exceptions inside the except condition like this**

```
    try:
       print(q)
       a = 8 / 0
    except error as err:
       if err is abc:
           new_method(err)
       elif err is xyz:
          new_method2(err)
       ....
```